# JavaFx Label - how to force a new line (line break)

Tags: javafx, label, newline

I am trying to write to a JavaFX label.
I can write successfully and use wrapping to make sure the text wraps to a new line if it is longer than the label.
My issue is I need to add text to the existing text which I can do, but I am unable to make the next text start on a new line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a newline character:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("Hello\nWorld");
```

Comment: hmm ... I prefer your earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351080/203657 - or maybe I don't understand what the OP really wants to know :)

Comment: @kleopatra "I am unable to make new text start on a new line": I interpret that to mean that the OP wants a new line at a specific point in the text.

Comment: ahh .. yeah, that could well be, my bad :)

Comment: i was being a dummy using /n not \n

Comment: And how to have same result using FXML? Escape character is not working here:
`<Label text="ac\ntive"/>`

Comment: Found it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093508/javafx-fxml-file-textarea-line-break-and-tab-in-text

`<TextArea prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="${'Multi\nLine\tTab'}" />`

Answer (score 10):

I have been looking for multiline label trick in `FXML` for some time and many times I visited this post (google displayed this result, a lot of frustration). So I think I will write it here.

I managed to find this code to display multiline:

```
<Label text="${'number of registered\nreaders'}"/>
```

But if I define variable

```
<fx:define>
    <String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="${'number of registered\nreaders'}"/> 
</fx:define>
```

then I have no idea how to refer to it, I can't use `$LABEL_01`.

---

In `FXML` you can also use this: `'&#xD;'`. Then this code works:

```
<fx:define>
    <String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="number of registered&#xD;readers"/> 
</fx:define>
```

And you can use `LABEL_01` like this:

```
<Label text="$LABEL_01"/>
```

Comment: regarding `$LABEL_01`, binding expressions dont have variable shorthand, so `${LABEL_01}` will work

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
 yourlabel.setText(yourLabel.getText() + System.lineSeparator() + "New String");
```